# the percentage of a JS date object within a range

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have three date objects.  How do I go about comparing them such that I can determine the relative disparity between them.

```
oldDate = newDate() - 5;
midDate = newDate() - 2.5;
newDate = newDate();
```

What percentage would midDate be between the two?

Comment: Get the difference between `midDate` and `oldDate`, and the difference between `newDate` and `oldDate`, divide them, and multiply this by 100 to convert to a percentage.

Comment: That's elementary school arithmetic, just convert it to Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, the result of that operation is `0.9999980779985906` and something relatively similar when it should read 0.01.

Comment: Remember JS has float errors. 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3

Comment: What is `newDate()`? Is it the same as `new Date()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to epoch time, then do the arithmetic.

```
var start = new Date("April 11, 2016");
var mid   = new Date("April 12, 2016");
var end   = new Date("April 13, 2016");

var total  = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
var offset = mid.getTime() - start.getTime();

var percentage = offset / total;
```